# Добавить скобки в массиве

Tags: python

Имеется функция:

```
def ts_key_bot(id):
        data = json.load(open('data_bot.json', 'r', encoding = 'utf=8'))
        for i in data["users"]["data"]:
            if i["id"] == int(id):
                c = []
                for b in i["user"]["user"]:
                    c.append([(str(b["num1"]) + " | " + str(b["num2"]) + " " + str(b["num3"]))])  
                    c[-1].append("белый")
                print(c)
```

После выполнения получаем:

```
[['1 | test1 test2', 'белый'], ['2 | test1 test2', 'белый']]
```

Подскажите, каким образом можно поменять функцию, что бы в каждом элементе массива были скобки:

```
[[('1 | test1 test2', 'белый')], [('2 | test1 test2', 'белый')]]
```

Comment: Если это Ваш полный код, то добавление `'белый'` добавьте через запятую в строчку выше. Что-то типа `c.append([(... + str(b["num3]), "белый")])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас список - превратите его в кортеж и заверните в список

```
arr = ['123', 456]

res = [tuple(arr)]
```